# Working with type inference and generic methods in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `Person` and two classes `Male`, `Female` that extend `Person`:

```
public class Male extends Person{ [...] }
```

In `Person`, there is a field `sex` that could discriminate between the subclasses, but `Person` can be used too.

I have a method `foo` that could return an object of type `Person`, `Male` or `Female`. Should the return type be achieved with generic method?

Something like that:

```
public <T> foo(Sex sex) {
    if (sex=Sex.M)
        return new Male();
    else if (sex=Sex.F)
        return new Female();
    else
        return new Person();
}
```

How should then I declare class `Person` and subclasses?

How can I use that method, if I don't know how to instantiate the object?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ??? test = foo(Sex.M);
    //working on test
}
```

EDIT:

Doing:

```
public Person foo(Sex sex) {
        if (sex=Sex.M)
            return new Male();
        else if (sex=Sex.F)
            return new Female();
        else
            return new Person();
}
```

In `main` can I use methods declared in `Male` or `Female`, even if they are declared in subclasses? Because `test` is of `Person` type.

Comment: You can also use overloading of the method and remove thr sex part

Comment: `sex="m"`, I think you should correct this part of your question. Moreover, `sex` is declared of type `Sex`; it is not a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Child is a Parent.

Just change your declaration `public <T> foo(Sex sex) {` to

`public Person foo(Sex sex) {`

Then again to test you can do

```
  Person test = foo(sex);
```

Note that, since you have no idea which Child you receive from foo method, you need to check before operating on it, if the operation is specific to Child.

Edit :

---

> In main can I use methods declared in Male or Female, even if they are declared in subclasses? Because test is of Person type.

That is what I added as a note. You cannot use directly. You can use only common things (varaibles and methods from parent). If you want to do some specific invocations from Child, you need to cast your `test` to that specific `Child` type.

Something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Person test = foo(sex);
   if(test instanceof Male) {
     Male m = (Male) test;
     // use m as male
   }
}
```

Why I used `test instanceof Male` Just to save myself from cast fail in case of other types.

Comment: But since then you just have the methods and attributes of Person and not the child or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcelHöll Yes. You are right. Added that as a note it my answer.

Comment: My Gosh! An `instanceof`!

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ With the cast to `Male` I see it's now possible to use the methods defined in the sublcasses. But what about the information stored in the `Male` subclass? It have a different costructor from `Person`, like, just for example, a field `int beardLength`

Comment: @Pleasant94 That you'll use in foo method while creating Male :)

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Even if this is a good solution to the problem, I have to change completely my implementation of classes and subclasses, because it's not possible for my kind of project to work always with `instanceof`, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `generics` here. Here `Person` is a `superclass` for Male and Female.
So, use Person in declarations where ever needed. Later on it can always accomodate the sub class instance.

Following will be fine in all the cases -

```
public Person foo(Sex sex) {
    if (sex="m")
        return new Male();
    else if (sex="f")
        return new Female();
    else
        return new Person();
}
```

This is because all the following assignments are correct.

```
Person a;
a = new Person(); //correct 
a = new Male(); //correct
a = new Female(); //correct
```

Comment: So in `main` I can do:
`Person test = foo(sex);
test.methodInMale();`
And it works?

Comment: @Pleasant94 no, it won't. It might work if you do `((Male)test).methodInMale();`, though you obviously run the risk of the cast failing if you have a Female in test

Comment: @Deltharis And what should I use for that kind of type inference (or what method should I use to get around that problem)? Because I don't know the type returned.

Comment: Thanks @Deltharis for pointing it out. If a method belongs only to the child and not the parent, as you ask in the updated part, it will give you a compilation error.

Comment: @Pleasant94 you need to use `instanceof` operator to ensure the type before casting. eg - `if( myObj instanceof Male) {...//Cast here }`

Comment: @Pleasant94 if you don't know the type returned don't call a method you can only call when you know that type basically. And if you really need to know it you'd probably be better off just calling different methods based on Sex to create the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

You are leveraging inheritance here and there is no need for mixing generics in. You can simply define `Person` as the return type - you will be able to return `Male` and `Female` instances too because those are `Person`s too.

```
public Person foo(Sex sex) { ... }
```

and then everything becomes clear:

```
Person test = foo(sex);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the `Person` class should not be instantiable. Are there any use cases in which you need to create an object of type `Person` and not of type `Male` of `Female`?

Leaving `Person` as a concrete class, you're trying to use *code reuse*, which is bad practice in Object-oriented programming.

> Prefer composition over inheritance

they said.

Anyway, using your solution there is another problem: You probably have an abstraction leak. Super-classes should not know anything about the possible types of available subclasses. If the method `foo` is located in `Person` class, it suffers exactly of this problem.

Finally, generics won't help you. You need to review your design. As suggested by someone in the comments to your question, a possible elegant solution should be the following:

```
abstract class Person {
    // Omissis
    public abstract String sex();
    // Omissis
}

class Male {
    // Omissis
    public String sex() {
        return "M";
    }
    // Omissis
    public static Male of() {
        return new Male();
    }
}

class Female {
    // Omissis
    public String sex() {
        return "M";
    }
    // Omissis
    public static Femaleof() {
        return new Female();
    }
}
```

So, if you need a method to create a new male or female person, you can have a dedicated type, a factory, like the following:

```
class PersonFactory {
    public Person build(String sex) {
        if ("M".equals(sex) return new Male();
        else return new Female();
    }
    public Male male() {
        return new Male();
    }
    public Female female() {
        return new Female();
    }
}
```

Instead of a dedicated type to build `Male`s and `Female`s you can use a `static` method `of` defined directly in both subclasses. This will close (SOLID speaking) your design to the add of new types of persons.

Clearly, all the behavior of a male or a female should be available also for a person, which means that you probably need more `abstract` methods in `Person` class.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't quite understand your objection to his`foo` method when you basically copied it (cutting down Person instantiation and cleaning accordingly), and just mentioned that it's in the proper factory class.

Comment: The problem with the function `foo` is its location. It should not be declared in the `Person` type. I do not like the _factory_ class, but if he needs a single place to build persons, I think there is not other solution. My solution transforms `Person` also in an `abstract` type (this is the most important change).

Comment: I don't see where he says it's in the Person type. I mean, it's possible that it's there, but no reason to suspect that either.

Comment: That costructor `foo` it's even in another package, I'm using that example just for abastraction to expose my problem.

Comment: Ok. The focus of my answer is that you should not be able to create an object of type  `Person`.

Comment: I get that, I'd upvote your answer, just waiting for you to edit that part out (and maybe to handle the situation he seems to expect, that someone is neither a male or female - that another subclass would be better than just using the parent class)

Comment: Which part, sorry?